# Not able to get datasource for collapsed tree nodes in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-treeview, kendo-datasource

I am unable to get full tree data when it is collapsed 
[click here for Demo](http://dojo.telerik.com/eQUxIzoB/2)

Comment: You did not specify what it is exactly what you want. Please ask a question the community can help you with. If possible, provide as much code as possible in the question section, instead of pasting a link.

Comment: I need a full json value after doing some action on tree like add, delete and sort without expand the tree

Answer (score 0):

**Try below code:**

```
$scope.getData = function () {
                $scope.updateddata = angular.copy($scope.treeData.options.data);

            }
```

you are using `$scope.treeData.view()`. It only gets the data that displays on the screen.

**Dojo Example:** [Click here for Demo](http://dojo.telerik.com/eQUxIzoB/3)

Comment: if you made any changes on tree like add , delete, sort the won't change

Comment: In that case you can use this code:   `$scope.getData = function () {
                    $scope.updateddata = angular.copy($scope.treeData._data);
                }`

Comment: in this we wont get sub item list